# How to wrap button's HTML in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I tried to wrap each `button` element's HTML into a div.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4qdbf7ns/)

> jQuery

```
$('button').each(function(){
    var markup = $(this).html();
    console.log(markup);


    //This doesn't work
    //markup.each(function(){
    //  $(this).wrap('<div></div');
    //})

    //This doesn't work either
    //markup.wrap('<div></div>');
});
```

I get `TypeError: markup.wrap is not a function` for the last not-working attempt and something similar to the 1st

My **final goal** is: wrap each button's content (it can include tags within too as shown in the JSFiddle) in a `div`

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not valid HTML to put `block-level elements` tags into a `<button>`. I mean... you *can* but...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over `.each()`.
`$("button")` is already a collection of all your `"button"` elements.

### Wrap the selector into another element:

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```js
$("button").wrap("<div />");
```

```css
div{
  background: #0FF1CE;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
```

### Wrap element's content into another element:

If you want to wrap everything an element has, into another element, use:
http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/

<sup>For your **notice**, it's incorrect HTML markup to use block level elements inside a `<button>` http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-button-element.html#the-button-element → so let's use `<span>` in this example:</sup>

```js
$("button").wrapInner("<span />");
```

```css
span{
  background: #0FF1CE;
  color:      #EFFEC7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button><i>Button</i> <b>1</b></button>
<button><i>Button</i> <b>2</b></button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but you got me wrong a bit. I need the markup to be like that ``<button><div class="mydiv">SomePreviousText/Markup</div></button>``. So as the ``div`` wraps what's inside the ``button`` tag (that's why I made a ``var markup`` and iterated each ``button``).

Comment: @knitevision it's not valid markup any way to populate `<button>` with inner (block-level) HTML elements like DIV. `<span>` is fine but not a `<div>`

Comment: I know, but Firefox and button and flex are not good friends so I rly need that fix... And "validity" of the markup doesn't mean much at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use wrapInner:

```
    $(this).wrapInner( "<div></div>" );
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hzj643tt/

Answer (score 1):

If interpret Question correctly, try using `.html()`

```
$("button").html(function(index, html) {
  return "<div>" + html + "</div>"
})
```